# String.fromCharCode(0) problem - actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, base64

I am trying to convert a `bytearray` into a `string`. The problem is whenever I try to append a `NULL` character using `String.fromCharCode(0)` it cuts off the end of the string and than I cant run it throw `base64`. I tried using `String.fromCharCode(32) (space)` instead but no luck.
Any ideas of how to resolve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert your data to a string, you can use directly `Base64Encoder::encodeBytes` to encode your ByteArray.

Comment: If you are using a `ByteArray` you are probably already using AS3. In any case, what you are trying to do is basically not possible - there cannot be a "0" in the string so you need to somehow pass your ByteArray directly to whatever encoder you are using. If there's no such encoder in AS2, you might have to write it yourself.